# Permutations of n numbers with no odd numbers next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

What is the number of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ permutations, in which neither two neighbouring numbers are odd?

Could somebody show me the reasoning that leads to the answer?

Comment: I do not understand your inclusion of the phrase `[even]` at the end of the sentence.  Do you wish for no odd numbers are adjacent *and* no even numbers are adjacent?  or is 1243 an acceptable permutation of this type and we allow even numbers to be adjacent as well?

Comment: @JMoravitz If no two neighboring numbers are odd, then also no two neighboring numbers are even, except in the case that $n$ is even and the endpoints are chosen to be both odd.  So the question is really three questions:  No consecutive odds, not consecutive evens, and no consecutive eithers..

Comment: @MarkFischler I gave an example of $1243$ where no odd numbers are adjacent, however an even number is adjacent to another even number.  Such a possibility can occur when $n$ is even, but not when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I mis-spoke.  I have corrected my comment.

Comment: The trick is to make a permutation of odd numbers and even numbers apart from each other. Now consider you have two permutations, pick one from each permutation over and over. Think about which one you should start with, which is dependent on if $n$ is even or odd. Jack D'Aurizio gives the solution that follows from this reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Break into cases:  Either $n=2k$ is even or $n=2k+1$ is odd.

Arrange the $k$ even numbers.  Give a bit of extra space to the left and right of each.  Using these as a barrier, we place the odd numbers into the gaps.  There are $k+1$ gaps total.

In the first case, exactly one of these gaps will remain unused.  In the second case, all gaps will be used.  Pick which gap if any is unused.  Then arrange the odd numbers within the gaps using at most one odd number per gap.

Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

There will be $k!(k+1)!$ arrangements in both cases.

Rewording to remove mention of $k$, there will be $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor !\lfloor \frac{n}{2}+1\rfloor!$ total arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, this question can have three possible meanings, and each meaning is an interesting question in itself.

Say you want to count permutations with no two consecutive odd numbers and no two consecutive even numbers. Then the solution of Jack D'aurizio holds; note that for odd $n=2k+1$ this solution is $(k+1)!k!$ (observe that the second $n/2$ is in a ceiling operator, not a floor).

Say you just require no consecutive odd numbers and $n=2k$ is even.  (This problem is isomorphic to no consecutive even numbers for the same $n$).

Then there are two classes of admissible permutations:

- Pure alternation of odd and even -- as before, there are $2 k! k!$ such permutations, since each of the odds and evens can be ordered independently, and the first number could be odd or even.
- Two odds are on the endpoints.  Here, there are $k-1$ positions for the inevitable pair of adjacent even numbers.  Again each of the odds and evens can be ordered independently, so this class numbers $(k-1) k! k!$.

Add those together and the answer for no two odds adjacent, when $n=2k$, is 
$(k+1)!k!$.

If $n=2k+1$ is odd, then the problem of no consecutive odd numbers is the same as no consecutive odds and no consecutive evens, since the endpoints need to be odd anyway, so the answer in that case is $(k+1)!k!$.
So the answer you are looking for now that the question has been changed to no consecutive odds only is 
$$ (k+1)! k!$$ for either $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$.

Finally, if $n=2k+1$ is odd, then the problem of no consecutive evens is the most interesting of these problems. The way to solve this is to notice that either the first position must contain an odd number, or there must be a sequence of EOO somewhere in the permutation, and before that the sequence must be 
EOEOEO...EOEOO.  So the string starts with between $0$ and $k$ EO pairs, each one of which contributes two possible arrangements of odds and evens (since the numbers after the EOO squense must alternate parity), except if you start with $k$ pairs, there is only one arrangement.  That makes $n$ possible arrangements in total.

So if $n=2k+1$ is odd, then the number of permutations with no consecutive *even* numbers is
$n(k+1)!k!$.